# apache mod-rewrite: Can I have different rules for POST and GET requests?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a rewrite rule that looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^foo/bar/([\w]+)/files/([\S\s]+)$ /mydirectory/$1/$2
```

I'd like to have GET requests go to /mydirectory/$1/$2 and POST requests go somewhere different.  Is this something that'll possible using mod-rewrite?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes - use THE_REQUEST variable.  See [the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Answer (score 2):

Great! Thank you SB.

Here's what I did, for reference:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} GET
RewriteRule ^foo/bar([\w]+)/files/([\S\s]+)$ /mydirectory/$1/$2

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} POST
RewriteRule ^foo/bar/([\w]+)/files/([\S\s]+)$ /somewherelse/$1/$2
```

This redirects POSTs to 'somewhereelse' and GETs to 'mydirectory'.